# How do I store my scraped values into a dataframe once all the pages are looped and values append into my lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

Currently, my dataframe is printing out 2 dataframes but I want it to simply be one dataframe with all the values passed on from `omp_name_lists and comp_rating_lists`. I know the function is passing values page by page so I would like to know how can I tell python wait for all the page values to append and then `create_dataframe`.

```
def get_data(get_comp_name,get_comp_rating):


    comp_name_lists, comp_rating_lists = [],[]
    for i, v in  zip(get_comp_name, get_comp_rating):
        comp_name_lists.append(i.a.text)
        comp_rating_lists.append(v.text)

    return create_dataframe(comp_name_lists,comp_rating_lists)

def create_dataframe(comp_name_lists,comp_rating_lists): # This is where 
    """This gets all of our data that we scraped and stores into a pandas dataframe"""
    df = pd.DataFrame({'CompanyName' : comp_name_lists, 'CompanyRating' : comp_rating_lists})
    df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
    print(df)
```

**Desired Output:**

```
  A              B
0 a              3
1 b              7
2 c              1
3 d              2
4 e              8
5 f              9
6 g              7
7 h              8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be one dataframe with all the values, so you should have a global variable 
 because it will be not re-initialize, unless you restart script. If you pass value by `return create_dataframe(comp_name_lists,comp_rating_lists)`, it will create a new space which independent from the others and the value of df is empty that mean you can not done what you expect in this way. In my consideration, create a dataframe after you finished fetching data

```
resultset = {'CompanyName' : [], 'CompanyRating' : []}

def get_data(get_comp_name,get_comp_rating):


    comp_name_lists, comp_rating_lists = [],[]
    for i, v in  zip(get_comp_name, get_comp_rating):
        comp_name_lists.append(i.a.text)
        comp_rating_lists.append(v.text)

    resultset["CompanyName"] += comp_name_lists
    resultset["CompanyRating"] += comp_rating_lists

def create_dataframe(data): # This is where 
    """This gets all of our data that we scraped and stores into a pandas dataframe"""
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
    print(df)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Dam global vars when I need them I never use them lol.